# Accessing Microsoft hosted CRM 4 using web services

Tags: .net, web-services, crm

I'm trying to perform a proof of concept of integration with CRM 4.0 for a project we are designing. Rather than installing the trial version which would require setting up Active Directory as well, I setup a trial hosted version here: http://crm.dynamics.com/en-gb/trial-overview

I am trying to establish a web services connection but I am getting a 401 Unauthorised error. Some of the code samples I found involve using the DiscoveredService but I cannot add a web reference to this in Visual Studio as it doesn't find it. The asmx file is there when accessed in the web browser but there is only an Execute method init.

I suppose my question is: Can the hosted Microsoft CRM solution be accessed using the CRM web services?

Thanks for your help,
John

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, download the Microsoft CRM SDK.  It contains code samples that are already set up to do this.